# React Native: How can I focus on ListView?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been working on focusing on ListView component.
Here's my code

```
class MyListView extends Component { 
    static propTypes = {
        navigator: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.listView.focus()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ListView
                ref={ref => { this.listView = ref }}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.listView}
                dataSource={cloneWithRows(listDataSource)}
                renderRow={(data) => <MyListViewCell
                    ...
                />}
            />
        )
    }
}
export default MyListView
```

but it just returns an error like "this.listView.focus is not a function"
I've searched lots of articles but I couldn't find the solution.
Any ideas?

Comment: What makes you think that `ListView` has a `focus()` method?

Comment: Only input elements have focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

componentDidMount does not guarantee that ref prop is called before componentDidMount is called. You should change for componentDidMount code to following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
       this.listView.focus()
   })

}
```

Also if you decide to use requestAnimationFrame function. It will be better you use it using TimerMixin (see [TimerMixin doc](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.33/docs/timers.html#timermixin)). Use [react-mixin](https://github.com/brigand/react-mixin) to implement Mixin in ES6 as suggested in TimerMixin doc.